# IPv6 forwarding not working

Tags: linux, centos, port-forwarding, ipv6

I have a server in a datacenter with native IPv6 connectivity. (I have a /48 block at my disposal.)

I want to use this server as a ipv6 tunnel server over openvpn, but I can't get it to work completely.

My server:
Linux, Centos 5.2
eth0 dual stacked ipv4/ipv6

```
ip addr list:
eth0
inet aa.bb.cc.dd/24 (my global IP address)
inet6 2001:aaaa:bbb::2/48 (2001:aaaa:bbb::1 is the default GW of my ISP)

sit2
link/sit 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
inet6 2001:aaaa:bbb:2::1/64

tun0
inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32
```

My client:
Mac OS 10.6

```
tun0: 10.8.0.2 --> 10.8.0.1
gif0 2001:aaaa:bbb:2::2 --> 2001:aaaa:bbb:2::1 prefixlen 128
```

route to default gw 2001:aaaa:bbb:2::1 (the ip of my server on the sit interface)

I think the mac side is OK, as a traceroute6 to ipv6.google.com gives 2001:aaaa:bbb:2::1 as the next hop, but it stalls there.
Pinging ipv6.google.com from the server works.
Ip6tables is turned off, and I did echo "1" to /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding.

Output from ip6tables -L:

```
ip6tables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output from sysctl -a |grep forward|grep ipv6:

```
net.ipv6.conf.sit2.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
```

**What's keeping my router from forwarding the packages between his two interfaces?**

Answer (score 3):

Putting a /64 from inside this /48 space behind another router (your diy tunnelbox) will not work because your ISP's router does not route the traffic for this /64 back to your tunnelbox, but expects the hosts to be directly in the local subnet.

Your ISP should not put a /48 on the link, but use a /64 instead.

Either you'll need to do some proxy-arp magic (haven't been there, wouldn't do that) or you'll tell your ISP to put a /64 on link, e.g. the first /64 in the /48. Then, your ISP also has to add a route to some other part of your /48 via your tunnelserver. (been there, have that running at my ISP in colocation). A possibility is to ask to route a /56 inside the /48 to your tunnelbox, so you can create tunnels which have one or multiple /64 on the other side. For the tunnels itself you can either also use /64's from the /56, or use one /64 with something like a /80 as tunnel itself.

(Note: 2001:A000::/20 is address space in use by APNIC, if you want to hide your actual adresses, it's better to use an address range like 2001:db8::/32 which is meant to be used for documentation purpose)

Answer (score 1):

The question is very old, but I've faced exactly the same problem today in 2023, and was stuggling to find a solution.
I could make the routing work by installing ndppd and configuring it in auto mode.
Config for this router setup should look like this:

```
proxy eth0 {
   rule 2001:aaaa:bbb::2/48 {
       auto
   }
}
```

More details on ndppd config
[ndppd config manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man5/ndppd.conf.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as he described. I indeed had to set arp proxying with ip.
Also check your routes to see if it's using your server as a gateway and not just the interface.